# How to ask pesmision from user to activate the background task?

Tags: windows-8, background-process, user-permissions

I have developed an Windows 8 application that uses the background task to retrieve data and activate live tiles feature. It all works fine but I need to go to the application settings and manually turn it on in order to make it work. Is it possible to programmatically request activation from user? Here is my code:

```
private void checkTaskRegistration()
        {
            bool isTaskRegistered = false;

            foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            {
                if (task.Value.Name == "TileUpdater")
                {
                    isTaskRegistered = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!isTaskRegistered)
            {
                registerBackgroundTask("TileUpdater", "BackgroundTasks.TileUpdaterBackgroundTask");
            }
        }

        private void registerBackgroundTask(string name, string entrypoint)
        {
            BackgroundTaskBuilder btb = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
            btb.Name = name;
            btb.TaskEntryPoint = entrypoint;
            btb.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));
            btb.AddCondition(new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable));
            BackgroundTaskRegistration task = btb.Register();
        }
```

First I check if the task already registered, and if it is not I register it.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. You just need to call:

```
BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
```

and that's it.